How do I run some script before the dev container starts?
I want to use docker with VSCode. However, because I need to use GUI interface, I need to connect the run some script before the running the container. My script looks like this:
# For Display, Connect to XServer
XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth
if [ ! -f $XAUTH ]; then
   xauth_list=$(xauth nlist $DISPLAY)
   xauth_list=$(sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' <<<"$xauth_list")
   if [ ! -z "$xauth_list" ]; then
       echo "$xauth_list" | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
   else
       touch $XAUTH
   fi
   chmod a+r $XAUTH
fi

# Prevent executing "docker run" when xauth failed.
if [ ! -f $XAUTH ]; then
  echo "[$XAUTH] was not properly created. Exiting..."
  exit 1
fi

docker run \
       -it \
       --rm \
       -v $REPO_DIRECTORY:/root/$REPO_NAME \
       --network host \
       --gpus all \
       --runtime=nvidia \
       --env="DISPLAY" \
       --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
       --env="XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH" \
       --volume="$XAUTH:$XAUTH" \
       $REPO_NAME:latest \
       bash

I am not sure how to convert the above process into devcontainer.json. It seems like all the command runs after the container starts.
Thank you!
